# Installing a package manually using apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, repository, apt-offline

I'm trying to install a deb package offline using `apt-get` command. From what I understand, I can download a package manually from the internet. Put it in the local repository folder (which is usually `/var/cache/apt/archives`). Then update the repository using `apt-get update`. And finally `apt-get install myPackage`

I tried these steps, but I keep getting the error `Unable to locate package uex_15.1.0.8_amd64`. What am I missing? or should I use `apt-offline`? If so, how?

BTW, the package `uex_15.1.0.8_amd64` is the package to install UltraEdit.

Comment: Your approach doesn't work. `apt` doesn't know the deb file is in the cache if you do it that way. Please give a specific example of what you are trying to do. And yes, I think you can use `apt-offline`, assuming you have `apt` configured correctly.

Comment: Could you please post content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file ?

Comment: What do you mean by a specific example? I specified everything in the question. But again the steps in more details. 1- Download the file 2- Save the file to `/var/cache/apt/archives` 3- run `sudo apt-get update` 4- run `sudo apt-get install uex_15.1.0.8_amd64`

Comment: Why not install with `dpkg -i`?

Comment: What package are you trying to install? `uex` isn't in Debian. Are you trying to use a third-party repository? What is the output of `apt-cache policy`?

Comment: @fkraiem That would only work if there are no additional dependencies which need to be installed.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Dependencies can be installed manually beforehand.

Comment: @fkraiem Certainly, if you know what they are. I think this is what `apt-offline` is designed to automate.

Comment: @FaheemMitha `dpkg` tells you what they are when you try to install the package.

Comment: @FaheemMitha It seems that `apt-offline` is mostly designed to manage a system which is completely offline, especially regarding upgrades, not really for installing a single package.

Comment: @fkraiem Yes, `apt-offline` is. But it isn't clear from the poster's question whether his system is offline or not. If it isn't, why doesn't he just use `apt` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two separate steps:

1. Install the package with `dpkg`.

   ```bash
   sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
   ```
2. That created missing dependencies. `apt-get` can fix missing dependencies automatically.

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

   That should also automatically finish configuring the original package. (So you will not likely need to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` yourself.)

#### Why `apt-get` Won't Do This

`apt-get` checks your configured software sources (repositories) and automatically downloads and installs packages. Except in the case where a configured repository is inaccessible, this does not enable an `apt-get install` command to succeed that would not otherwise succeed. If the package isn't in one of your repositories, `apt-get` will not know to install it even if the .deb file happens to be in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.